# Friend function Random behaviour

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

class FooA
{
private :
friend class FooB;
    void Hello();
    void Hello2();
private:
    void Hello3();
    int m_iData;
};

class FooB
{
    void fun()
    {
        FooA objA;
        objA.Hello();  // right
        objA.Hello2(); // right
        objA.Hello3(); // right
        //ojbA.m_iData = 0; // compile error 
    }
};
```

usually if we access Data member Function or Member variable which is private by an object directly throws error.

but in this scenario how it is able to access Hello(),Hello2(),Hello3() Functions and why it's throwing error in accessing m_iData.

Comment: Did you really type `ojbA`? Please show an example program that actually causes the error you're asking about, and the actual error message produced.

Answer (score 1):

The b and the j in `objA` have been swapped to form the unknown identifier `ojbA`.

Change `ojbA.m_iData = 0;` to `objA.m_iData = 0;`

Comment: Thank you renspaceyi.. It's Typo error.